# Don't hide input accessoryView when keyboard hides

Tags: ios, swift, swift5, inputaccessoryview

i want inputAccessoryView to not to hide when keyboard dissmiss. I tried by changing the frame when keybaord hides but it not working

```
     customView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 10, height: 88))
     customView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
     textview.inputAccessoryView = customView



    // Tracking the keyboard status
     NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillBeHidden), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)


    @objc func keyboardWillHide(sender: NSNotification) {        

        self.customView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.view.frame.size.height-88, width: 10, height: 88)
        
        
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @BlindNinja, i am so dumb. i am trying it , thank you so much

Comment: I have added it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add that view on to current view. by setting it as `inputAccessoryView`, You are basically adding it on first responder's view which in this case is a keyboard.

Try this -

```
@objc func keyboardWillHide(sender: NSNotification) {        

    self.customView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.view.frame.size.height-88, width: 10, height: 88)
    
    self.view.addSubView(self.customView)
}
```